# Is “occurence” a word?

Tags: orthography, is-it-a-word, historical-change

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&query=occurence

It seems that *occurence* is not a word, but a friend said it is because he says he found it in the OED.

Comment: You're misspelling it: *occur**r**ence*.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought too. Be he found "occurence" in the OED

Comment: Apparently, it used to be spelled with one r. And now I see why I get spell-checked nearly every time I use the word.  https://www.amazon.com/Very-Best-Ambrose-Bierce-Including-ebook/dp/B01DNYFWN4/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1519098296&sr=1-1&keywords=9781473360372&dpID=51leW18C33L&preST=_SY445_QL70_&dpSrc=srch

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Occurence-Diseases-Adult-Classic-Reprint/dp/033291108X/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1519098410&sr=1-6&keywords=occurence

Comment: Please explain what you mean for something to “be” a word. It’s not a ham sandwich, you know, so it rather looks like a word to me. The OED always gives all historical spellings for a word, even from before we had standardized spellings. So for example [this one](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130193) was sometimes spelled *accoranse* back in the 1500s, as well as *accurauntes* for the plural. Does that mean those “are” “words” for your purposes?

Comment: @tchrist I suppose my definition of "a word" is one that I could use in an email.

Comment: @Apollo Only if you don't mind people thinking you don't know how to spell. :)

Answer (score 3):

You say that your friend found the word "occurence" in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130193?redirectedFrom=occurence#eid) (note that you weren't searching the OED in your link; the OED is a premium historical dictionary of English), which is technically true. It's listed as one of the forms of the word **occurrence**:

> Forms:  15 **accoranse**, 15 **accurauntes** (plural), 15– **occurrence**, 16 (18– irreg[ular]) **occurence**

It has nowhere near the popularity of the two *r* spelling, according to [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=occurence%2C+occurrence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coccurence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coccurrence%3B%2Cc0), but it is [used nonetheless](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22occurence%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

You will not find this spelling in "regular" dictionaries. It is considered to be a misspelling of "occurrence", as you can see in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/occurence).

Comment: If figure that that *irreg.* label means it’s been considered a misspelling since the 1800s. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems occurrence used to be spelled with just one [r](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/033291108X).

> This book is a reproduction of an important historical work.
>   *The Occurence of Diseases of Adult Bees*

On Amazon books, there are nearly 500 hits for [**occurence**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1286605679) spelled with one r. Many of them are quite literally spelled the same way in the texts, and most are scientific textbooks from around 100 years ago.

On Google Books, I got 285,000 hits for the word. So, it is a word that is still in print or texts all over the internet. It may be obsolete, for many (or most) people, but it's still technically an English language word.

I happen to like old books quite a lot, so outdated spelling doesn't bother me at all.

Edit: the reproduction books are unreliable for use as sources. But there are enough instances of the word being spelled with one r, such as in all these scientific reports from NASA, just to name one:

[Archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=occurence&sin=TXT&and[]=subject%3A%22NASA%20Technical%20Reports%20Server%20%28NTRS%29%22)

[Time occurence](https://archive.org/stream/basicradiopropag05inte#page/n1/mode/2up/search/occurence) or **occurence time** is evidently a scientific term, which may be [outdated](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Occurence_time&redirect=no).

Comment: It seems less common than one might think at first glance. Maybe it's just a word that lots of people (like me) have trouble spelling correctly. But even the Library of Congress has the title of the Bee book spelled that way (with one r): https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchCode=LCCN&searchArg=unk82076982&searchType=1&permalink=y On the other hand, I found an original of the same book scanned on Archive.org, spelled correctly. However, NASA and a bunch of other scientific agencies, have lots of papers in their files showing fairly common usage of "occurence".

Comment: https://thesaurus.plus/related/frequency_of_occurrence/occurence I'm finding some obscure (to me) uses of occurence. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Occurence_time&redirect=no https://quizlet.com/122440790/judaism-sacred-times-flash-cards/